# ¿Cómo puedo anular una regla en el firewall desde el sonicwall?

Tags: redes, firewall

**Contexto**
Se me ha sido bloqueado por medio del sonicwall que el juego league of legends se conecte a la red. Tengo acceso al sonicwall y ya he intentado montones de cosas para ver si puedo anular las reglas que me bloquean eso.

**Desde el Access Rules - esta relga aparecía denegada**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y efectivamente, yo la habilité hago ping a alguna dirección IP agrupada en LOL-Services y sale exitoso. Lo que sucede es que haciendole un estudio de red al juego me dice esto:

```
Ping to 138.0.13.100 Game Servers (MIA): 
Haciendo ping a 138.0.13.100 con 32 bytes de datos:
Estad¡sticas de ping para 138.0.13.100:
    Paquetes: enviados = 4, recibidos = 0, perdidos = 4
    (100% perdidos),

Prueba 3 de 8: LQ: 
No se puede resolver el nombre del sistema de destino lqak.la1.lol.riotgames.com.


Prueba 4 de 8: LQ2: 
Traza a la direcci¢n prod.la1.lol.riotgames.com [66.151.33.24]
sobre un m ximo de 20 saltos:

  1    24 ms    42 ms    18 ms  10.141.16.1 
  2    35 ms    16 ms    15 ms  10.166.51.26 
  3    20 ms    15 ms    15 ms  10.166.51.25 
  4    30 ms    38 ms    31 ms  static-adsl200-24-34-84.epm.net.co [200.24.34.84] 
  5    38 ms    34 ms    39 ms  static-adsl200-24-34-107.epm.net.co [200.24.34.107] 
  6    29 ms    29 ms    30 ms  206.223.124.158 
  7    45 ms    44 ms    44 ms  globenet-81.as52320.net [200.16.69.81] 
  8    67 ms    65 ms    64 ms  globenet-60.as52320.net [200.16.69.60] 
  9    73 ms    72 ms    75 ms  138.204.238.163 
 10    74 ms    81 ms    77 ms  104.160.136.52 
 11     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
 12     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
 13     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
 14     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
 15     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
 16     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
 17     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
 18     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
 19     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
 20     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.


Prueba 6 de 8: NA: 

Traza a 192.64.170.107 sobre caminos de 20 saltos como m ximo.

  1    16 ms    17 ms    19 ms  10.141.16.1 
  2    21 ms    15 ms    23 ms  10.166.51.26 
  3    15 ms    15 ms    16 ms  10.166.51.25 
  4    16 ms    22 ms    21 ms  static-adsl200-24-33-235.epm.net.co [200.24.33.235] 
  5    61 ms    60 ms    63 ms  static-adsl200-24-33-243.epm.net.co [200.24.33.243] 
  6    70 ms    60 ms    61 ms  jax-b1-link.telia.net [62.115.146.170] 
  7    76 ms    76 ms     *     atl-b22-link.telia.net [62.115.119.155] 
  8    86 ms    85 ms    88 ms  chi-b21-link.telia.net [62.115.113.19] 
  9    86 ms    98 ms    92 ms  riot-ic-315569-chi-b21.c.telia.net [62.115.63.66] 
 10    88 ms    91 ms    89 ms  104.160.131.44 
 11    90 ms    90 ms    89 ms  104.160.131.101 
 12     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
 13     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
 14     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
 15     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
 16     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
 17     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
 18     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
 19     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
 20     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
```

Lo que más me inquieta es que en ningún menú del sonicwall se encuentra algo relacionado con esas direcciones ip que están siendo bloqueadas.

**¿Qué me recomiendan?**

Comment: Hay reglas que se aplican por temáticas, por ejemplo, sexo esplicito, drogas alcohol y tabaco, violencia, etc. Puede que tu ip este restringida por alguna de estas configuraciones y no te deje salir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las direcciones que resuelve tu ping son dinámicas, por lo que es inviable encontrar alguna regla asociada a esas direcciones, por eso no encuentras nada. 
Deberías buscar sí se están negando "por aplicación", los firewall utilizan algo conocido como "Application Filtering" (La tecnología varía de acuerdo al fabricante), a través de ella se clasifican las aplicaciones como "Gaming", "Social Network", etc. Probablemente los servicios de tu juego estén negados a través de esas categorías, si ese es el caso y administras el firewall, bastará con agregar una excepción.

Comment: Hola, por ingeniería social sé que el Sonicwall no posee ese Application Filtering porque dice la persona a la que le saqué la info, que se necesita una licencia o algo así para aplicar eso y pues, eso no se ha hecho.